# Storing Rich Text In My Database

Tags: angularjs, json, asp.net-mvc

I have a site that has a rich text editor. However, after editing and ensuring that my changes are being saved, once the content is displayed it loses most of its styling.

For example I could save this: `<p style="font-size:22px">Hello world</p>`

However, once I return that from the database I get this `<p>Hello world</p>` so my styling is completely lost.

I am using CKEditor, ASP.NET MVC, and Angular for my project. Once I am done editing the model gets sent to the controlle as JSON. I checked the database once I stored the info and it still had my styling.

Once I get the data back into the controller (when I am requesting to load my rich text into a view) I check to make sure that it still has my styling, which it does.

Then I serialize it into JSON (because the rich text is part of an object and I want the whole object).

Once it is returned to the page all of my styling is gone. So I figure that `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(MyObject)` is messing with my inline styles.

Can anyone help me figure out how to make Newtonsoft.JSON leave my styles alone?\

Thanks!

Comment: since I am using Angular I do `ng-bind-html="vm.Content"` in a div

Comment: I recommend to save this html into varbinary form in database as a byte array. And when fetching just turn that byte array.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out and, quite frustratingly, it had nothing to do with how I was storing the data or serializing it.

As it turns out I had to add `$scope.Content = $sce.trustAsHtml(result.SomeData)` to the data I was receiveing.

Once I added that then I was getting the proper styling.